# wordpress how to set user email and change user role programmatically

Tags: wordpress

is there a way to set the email and change the user role of a specific user from subscriber to vendor please? I tried this but it did not work.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_meta=get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles=$user_meta->roles; 
 if (in_array("subscriber", $user_roles)){
$user_id_s = (int) $_POST[ $user_id ]; // correct ID
wp_update_user( array(
    'ID' => $user_id_s,
    'user_email' => $_POST[ $current_user ]
   ) );
```

Comment: Where is `$current_user` and `$user_id` coming from?  Why would you re-assign the user_id?  `$user_id_s = (int) $_POST[ $user_id ]; // correct ID` if the user is on this page?  Please add more details to your question, including the complete function you're calling here so somebody can help.

Comment: `$current_user` gets the current user name and `$user_id` is for the current user id, i re-assigned because i wanted to be sure it got it in int format. that is actually the complete function. disregard it if its nonsense please. just help me by showing me how you'll do it

Comment: Where is the email address you are trying to update?  Why?  Did the user not use their correct email when they registered?

Comment: The email is to be changed to the user name of the user and I also want to change the user role.

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally update a user role, or just update a user role in any way, you use `$user->set_role()` more specifically the method of the WP_User Class `WP_User::set_role()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/set_role/

Not so sure about the rest of your stuff here (like where the $_POST data comes from), but this will set the role, and update the email address.

**Be aware** that if you update the user's email address, they will receive an email from the website telling them that their email address has been changed.

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
if ( in_array( "subscriber", $user_roles ) ) {
    // Remove Role Subscriber
    $current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
    // Set Role to whatever you want here.
    $current_user->set_role( 'role_you_want' );
    wp_update_user( array(
        'ID' => $current_user->ID, // getting user id from get_current_user
        'user_email' => $_POST[ $current_user ]
    ) );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for vendor role, I tried to convert subscriber to vendor but it didn't work.

Comment: This definitely works... the question is how are you triggering it, and is `vendor` the name that is stored in the database?